Resolve Multidimensional Array using Javascript
When I do.
I receive as the screenshot attached.
But I need one array having each array as a whole number.
'use strict'
const { helper, browserstackBase } = require('@core/IQAir')
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const { initializeBrowser } = require('@core/IQAir/Automation-Library/library')

class USaqMajorCityRankingTable extends browserstackBase {
 
  async execute(driver) {
    await driver.get('www.iqair.com/us/world-air-quality')
    await driver.sleep(2000)
    await initializeBrowser(driver)
    await driver.sleep(2000)
   
const aqiData = await driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath("//table[@class = 'ranking__table ng-star-inserted']//td/p"));
   await helper.sleep(2000);
        await helper.sleep(2000);
        for (const aqi of aqiData){
            await helper.sleep(2000);
            const a = await aqi.getText()
           const promise1= Promise.resolve(a)
promise1.then((value) => {

    });
      }
  }
 
}
module.exports = new USaqMajorCityRankingTable().runTest()

for (const aqi of aqiData){
           
            const a = await aqi.getText()
const promise1= Promise.resolve(a)
promise1.then((value) => {
const flattened = [].concat(...value);
console.log (flattened)

Can Anyone please help!!
enter image description here
I am confused if it is a 2D array, because, if I want to return [0][0] or [0][1]
I receive an error:
"cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"


I used, but didn't work

Where are you getting that error?

@CodingEnthusiast I need those numbers in each array as a whole number. but it returns Nan/undefined

and what does aqi.getText() returns? does it returns a comma seperating string containing multiple numbers or what?

It returns the numbers, but as text in an array

aqi.getText() must be returning a number as string,
So try this:
var array = []
for (const aqi of aqiData) {
    const a = aqi.getText();
    array.push(parseInt(a));
}
console.log(array);


Now it returns adding each number in next array and last array has all the numbers. Do you know how to call only the last array?
[ 186 ]
[ 186, 162 ]
[ 186, 162, 153 ]
[ 186, 162, 153, 145 ]
[ 186, 162, 153, 145, 138 ]
[ 186, 162, 153, 145, 138, 122 ]
[
186, 162, 153,
118
]
[
186, 162, 153,
145, 138, 122,
118, 110
]
[
186, 162, 153,
145, 138, 122,
118, 110, 109
]
[
186, 162, 153, 145,
138, 122, 118, 110,
109, 105
]

you must have added console.log to the loop but i added that after the loop

It worked. Thank you so much
